# Is there a `.map` like function for objects? To create a new object with the same keys

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, functor

With an array we can use the `.map` method to create a new map with the same array structure (ie. the same number of elements).

eg.

```
const array = [2, 4, 6]; 
const newArray = array.map(v => v *2); //[4, 8, 12];
```

I believe in functional programming this makes the array object what is called a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor).

With objects I want to do something similar - I want to create a new object with the same structure (same keys), as well as the same functions etc as the original object.

eg.

```
const obj = {
    foo: 2, 
    bar: 4, 
    biz: 6
}; 

const newObj = obj.map(v => v *2); // {foo: 4, bar: 8, biz: 12}
```

The way I'm currently doing this is by using `Object.entries` and `.reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
    foo: 2, 
    bar: 4, 
    biz: 6
}; 

const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,cur) => {
    return {
        ...acc, 
        [cur[0]]: cur[1] * 2
    }
}, {}); 

console.log(newObj);
```

I'm wondering - is there currently an object method that would let me do this that I'm missing? Or a proposal to add one?

Comment: You're not missing anything, and AFAIK there is no proposal on deck to add it. A lot of libraries offer such functionality, and as you've discovered it's not too hard to write one yourself: `const map = (o, f) => Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => (acc[k] = f(v), acc), {});` its even a one-liner if you golf it.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's not old, but: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-map :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no native map for objects, but can easily make one. I think entries is the simplest.

```js
const obj = { foo: 2, bar: 4, biz: 6 }

const objMap = (obj, fn) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([k, v], i) => [k, fn(v, k, i)]
    )
  )

console.log(
  objMap(obj, v => v * 2),
  objMap(obj, (v, k) => `${k}-${v}`), 
  objMap(obj, (v, _, i) => v * i)
)
```

Comment: I would rather have four separate functions, `map`, `mapWithKey`, `mapWithIndex`, and `mapWithKeyAndIndex`, instead of one function that does everything.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` function for objects is easy enough to define.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "map", {
    value(mapping) {
        const oldEntries = Object.entries(this);
        const newEntries = oldEntries.map(([key, val]) => [key, mapping(val)]);
        return Object.fromEntries(newEntries);
    }
});

const obj = { foo: 2, bar: 4, baz: 6 };

const result = obj.map(x => 2 * x);

console.log(result);
```

Note that this is different from kornieff's [`objMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58945273/783743) function because the mapping function can't access or change the key. Hence, it's the correct implementation of the [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) type class for objects.

---

As a bonus, let's implement some other useful type classes for objects. First, the [`Representable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.2.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html) type class.

```js
Object.tabulate = table => new Proxy({}, {
    get: (_, key) => table(key)
});

const object = Object.tabulate(key => {
    if (key === "foo") return 10;
    if (key === "bar") return 20;
    return 30;
});

console.log(object.foo); // 10
console.log(object.bar); // 20
console.log(object.baz); // 30
```

The `tabulate` function can be used to define various useful type classes such as `Monad` and `Comonad`. For example, let's implement the [`Distributive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.3.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive) type class. I'll leave the implementation of the other type classes as an exercise for the reader.

```js
Object.tabulate = table => new Proxy({}, {
    get: (_, key) => table(key)
});

const distribute = functor => Object.tabulate(key =>
    functor.map(object => object[key]));

const result1 = distribute([ { foo: 10, bar: 20 }, { foo: 30, bar: 40 } ]);

console.log(result1.foo); // [ 10, 30 ]
console.log(result1.bar); // [ 20, 40 ]

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "map", {
    value(mapping) {
        const oldEntries = Object.entries(this);
        const newEntries = oldEntries.map(([key, val]) => [key, mapping(val)]);
        return Object.fromEntries(newEntries);
    }
});

const result2 = distribute({ a: { foo: 10, bar: 20 }, b: { foo: 30, bar: 40 } });

console.log(result2.foo); // { a: 10, b: 30 }
console.log(result2.bar); // { a: 20, b: 40 }
```

Note that `distribute` expects an object that has a `map` method, which is why we defined the `map` method on `Object.prototype`. However, we could have used the [`Yoneda`](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-yoneda) lemma to get around this restriction.

Comment: This is an inspiring use of the `Proxy` type.

Comment: @bob It works because you can think of an object as a function from strings (i.e. property names) to values. For example, the object `{ foo: 10, bar: 20 }` is isomorphic to the function `key => key === "foo" ? 10 : key === "bar" ? 20 : undefined`. The function `object => key => object[key]` witnesses the homomorphism from objects to functions, and the function `Object.tabulate` from my answer witnesses the reverse homomorphism from functions to objects. Composing the two should be equivalent to the identity function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```js
const obj = {
    foo: 2, 
    bar: 4, 
    biz: 6
}; 

const x = Object.keys(obj).map(o => {
 return {[o]: obj[o] * 2}
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using `.reduce()` is like this, making use of destructuring to read a little bit easier ( I think )

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 2,
  bar: 4,
  biz: 6
};

const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce(
  (acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: value * 2}), {}
);

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: You see that I posted this solution in my answer?

Comment: I was merely showing another way to handle the function, that I felt could add more clarity to some people

Comment: Sure fair enough. I think destructuring the array is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy experimenting a bit of functional apis in your code, 
then you could consider to use a functional library (such as Ramda),

It doesn't only introduce the functor api for objects (map), but also other cool stuff!

```js
const input = { a: 1, b: 44, c: 77 };

const doubled = R.map(R.multiply(2), input);

console.log(
  `doubling input`, 
  doubled,
);


// and a lot more...
const odds = R.filter(R.modulo(R.__, 2), input);

console.log(
  `filtering odds only of input`, 
  odds,
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function mapValues of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues)

const array = [2, 4, 6];

_.mapValues(array, v => v * 2)